# Keeping only specific columns and a reference column in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics

I have a large matrix that looks like something like this, with more columns and rows

```
---    CellName1 CellName2 CellName3
Gene A    1           2        3
Gene B    4           5        6
Gene C    7           8        9 
Gene D    10          11       12
```

This matrix extends for several thousands of columns and rows.  I only need about 13 columns for the spreadsheets, the headers of which I have listed in a .txt file

What is the best way to retain only the columns with specific headings (those in the text file) and keep the reference column (Gene A, Gene B etc)?

I tried to make an array of strings out of the names of the columns wanted, but I got an unexpected symbol error:

```
rsem.genes.tpm <- read.delim("~/Desktop/Desktop/rsem.genes.tpm.matrix", header=FALSE)
View(rsem.genes.tpm)
library("cluster", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")

wanted<-c("cy82-CD45-pos-2-C04-S508-comb”, "Cy74_CD45_A06_S390_comb”, “Cy74_CD45_C07_S415_comb”, “Cy74_CD45_H08_S476_comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-1-A03-S3-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-A10-S970-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-B03-S975-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-B09-S981-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-B12-S984-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-C10-S994-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-C12-S996-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-D09-S1005-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-D10-S1006-comb”, “cy53-1-CD45-pos-2-H05-S1049-comb”, “cy58-1-CD45-pos-A09-S585-comb”)  # Concatenates character strings into a vector
Error: unexpected symbol in "wanted<-c("cy82-CD45-pos-2-C04-S508-comb”, "Cy74_CD45_A06_S390_comb"
```

I think I want to use some combination of the keep and drop functions, but I'm not sure how to implement them

Comment: This is certainly due to this `”` which should be `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s create some example data:

```
set.seed <- 123
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10,25,replace = TRUE),nrow = 5))
df$gene <- c(paste0('gene',LETTERS[1:5]))
```

say you want to keep only columns : ‘V1’, ‘V2’ and ‘V5’ :

```
to.keep <- c('V1','V2','V5')
> df[,c('gene',to.keep)]
    gene V1 V2 V5
1 Gene A  6  1  5
2 Gene B  9  4  1
3 Gene C  7  7  8
4 Gene D  4 10  1
5 Gene E 10  4  4
```